# Hide specific elements using jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

We have issues with our code:

```js
function remove_single_entry_if_empty() {
  $(".single-entry").each(function() {
  var ids = $(this).attr('id');
      let a = (ids);
        for ( let i = 0; i < a.length; a++ ) {
          let x = document.getElementById(a);
          if ( x.getElementsByClassName('entry_times-wrapper').length === 1 ) {
            var c = x.getElementsByClassName('entry_times-wrapper').length === 1;
          x.style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
    });
}
```

HTML Structure:

```html
<div class="single-entry" id="9127">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <!-- this is where the <a> tags is. -->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

We have an HTML tag with the class `single-entry`. This class exist multiple times but each with a unique ID specified. The class name called `entry_times-wrapper` (which is a child element of variable `X`) has also multiple `<a>` tags.

What we want to do: if all items in class `entry_times-wrapper` are hidden (with display `none`), then hide the `single-entry` class for only that specific ID. For now, this code as described above will actually hide all these single entries.

How can we do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use a single line of jQuery which selects all the `.single-entry` elements which contain a hidden `.entry_times-wrapper` and then hide them. Try this:

```js
$('.single-entry:has(.entry_times-wrapper:hidden)').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="single-entry" id="9127">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <a href="#">Visible...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-entry" id="9128">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <a href="#" style="display: none">Not visible...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-entry" id="9120">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <a href="#">Visible...</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this workaround, we implemented and it works smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo with several `<div>`s and `<a>`s:

```js
$("button").click(function(){ $(".single-entry").add("a").show();});
$(".entry_times-wrapper a").click(function(){ $(this).hide();checkVis();})

// this needs to be called every time an <a> element is hidden or made visible again:
function checkVis(){
  $(".single-entry").each(function(){
    $(this).toggle($(".entry_times-wrapper a:visible",this).length>0)
  });
}
```

```css
.single-entry {background-color:#ccc; padding:6px;
               border: 1px black solid; margin: 4px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>show all links again</button><br>
<div class="single-entry" id="9127">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <a href="#">first link<br></a>
        <a href="#">second link<br></a>
        <a href="#">third link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-entry" id="9128">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <a href="#">fourth link<br></a>
        <a href="#">fifth link<br></a>
        <a href="#">sixth link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="single-entry" id="9129">
   <div class="entries_wrapper">
      <div class="entry_times-wrapper">
        <a href="#">seventh link<br></a>
        <a href="#">eighth link<br></a>
        <a href="#">ninth link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for a demo, I do understand the working of jQuery better now.